# How to list all not versioned files and directories in a Git working copy?

Tags: git, file

I'm developing on a VM and would like to see, which files and directories I need to add manually to my web directory on the remote server when I will be deploying the project (e.g. files with environment specific settings / credentials). How can I get a list of these files / directories?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git ls-files -o
```

The -o option of ls-files will show untracked files.

If you would like untracked directories listed as directories and not all the individual files you can do:

```
git ls-files -o --directory
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `git ls-files -o` shows all untracked files, but no directories. Is it possible to display the files an the dirs? That means: If we have a dir `foo` with the files `bar` and `baz`, `/foo` should be displayed and not `/foo/bar`, `/foo/baz`.

Answer (score 7):

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

- `--others` option shows `untracked` files.
- `--exclude-standard` option excludes the files that are included in `gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`.

See [git-ls-files](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The command shows only the files in untracked diresctories. How to display untracked directories as one item per directory (If we have a dir `foo` with the files `bar` and `baz`, `/foo` should be displayed and not `/foo/bar`, `/foo/baz`.) and untracked files in tracked directories?

Comment: This is from `man git-ls-files`: `--directory
           If a whole directory is classified as "other", show just its name (with a trailing slash) and not its whole contents.`

So the command becomes: `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory`

Comment: And untracked files in tracked directories are displayed just as normal. Nothing extra to do for them.

Comment: I think, `git ls-files --others --directory` is, what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
git status -uall
```

This command will show all untracked files and directories including untracked files in untracked directories. Use `-unormal` to hide untracked files in untracked directories.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The command shows only the files in untracked diresctories. How to display untracked directories as one item per directory (If we have a dir `foo` with the files `bar` and `baz`, `/foo` should be displayed and not `/foo/bar`, `/foo/baz`.) and untracked files in tracked directories?

Comment: `git status -unormal` will only display untracked files in tracked directories plus untracked directories.